# Color picker for Chrome

Tags: gratis, chrome, color

There is a question about a general color picker for the computer, but is there a Chrome extension for color picking?

By this I mean, a pointer that can zoom in and tell me the HTML hex color code and RGB number.

I need it to be:

- free
- a chrome extension (so I can use it on Windows and OSX)
- allowing me to zoom in to certain parts of a webpage
- working on local files as well
- show hex code and RGB number

This will be useful when I like a certain colour scheme for a website and would like to try using it in other things

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found something similar to what I wanted, and it's built into Chrome!

It's in ***developer tools*** (F12 on Windows, Option+cmd+I on OSX):

Double click the colour shown in the 'Styles' tab and you will be shown with a colour picker. You get the current pixel you are over magnified and a click will show you the HTML code where you can copy it.

I'm choosing this over @Timmy's answer because it **works on local files**.

What it doesn't do (that I would have liked):

- show me the RGB code (although a quick Google of the html code will show me the rgb one)
- can't exactly zoom in (but the magnified pixel works just fine :)

[image]

<sub>click image for larger view</sub>

Answer (score 2):

## [Eye Dropper](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/eye-dropper/hmdcmlfkchdmnmnmheododdhjedfccka) & [ColorZilla](http://www.colorzilla.com/chrome/)

They are Google Chrome extensions for picking colors from a webpage. They are very similar, and only meet some of your requirements so I'm combining them in one answer. They both:

- Are free
- Are Chrome extensions
- Have no zoom functionality, but they show a preview of the current pixel under the mouse pointer
- Do not work on local files (a possible workaround is using <kbd>Print Sreen</kbd> and uploading screenshots, or using a non-extension app)
- Show hex and RGB codes, among other formats

  ```
                           Eyedropper                                       ColorZilla
  ```

[image]

Comment: @ṧнʊß Thank you :). You could also use the Windows Magnifier with any of these tools. Keyboard shortcut: Win & NumPad+

Comment: True, but I'll see if there are any extensions with built in magnification, but I don't really care about that very much because you said it shows you the pixel under the mouse. Most importantly - support for local files.